# Raleway font adding additional padding to the top of text on Windows only

Tags: html, css, font-face

I'm using the Raleway font provided by Google's Web Fonts and I have found that on my Windows 7 machine (tested with IE9, Firefox, Chrome, Safari) that addtional padding appears to be added to the top of text. When I check it out on my Mac (tested with Firefox, Chrome, Safari) it's fine. If I pick a different font from Google's Web Fonts, it's fine (at least with the ones I checked out). Has anyone else ever come across this and know of a way I can fix it?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?></title>

        <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100&v1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="test">
            Hello World
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}fieldset,img{border:0;}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;}li{list-style:none;}caption,th{text-align:left;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal;}q:before,q:after{content:'';}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal;}sup{vertical-align:text-top;}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom;}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;}input,textarea,select{*font-size:100%;}legend{color:#000;}

body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

.test {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 4em;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    background: rgb(0,0,0);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      color: #fff;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some code (http://jsfiddle.net) and optionally a screenshot?

Comment: Code, NP. Screenshot I can do this evening when I get home.

Comment: Checked in IE8 and FF 3.6 on WIN XP - I see same amount of padding on top as at the bottom. I don't see the font in IE though without specifying color in css for test class - just FYI.

Comment: @cvandal - Can you show it in one OS vs another?

Comment: That's right, but if you view it on a OS X, the padding at the top will not be there.

Comment: I will upload a screen shot of it in OS X when I get home. I haven't got acess to a Mac at work.

Comment: According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362966/text-rendering-between-os-x-and-windows-throwing-off-my-padding you might have to specify line-height

Comment: @AR - I thought so too at first, but then I tried it: http://jsfiddle.net/HjChG/1/ At least in FF4 on Win7, the text is at the top but the `y` falls well below. Not sure that's what the OP wants.

Comment: @AR - http://i.imgur.com/442WU.png

Comment: Oh, I see but it's just the font. Top of 'y' is aligned with the rest. It actually looks kinda cool with 'y' stcking below a bit))). You can add padding-bottom: 8px; to test class. But then other letters would be a bit above the line. just the way this font is.

Comment: @AR - Can you click on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HjChG/1/ and do a similar screenshot?

Comment: @Jared, adding a line-height of 30px and then a padding-bottom of 8px seems to be exactly what I am after! I'll confirm this tonight when I can hop on my mac and see how it shows up.

Comment: Well, like I said, adding a line-height of 0.8 and a padding-bottom of 8px worked great in IE9, Firefox, Chrome and Safari on Windows but i'm afraid it's still borked on my Mac. I guess I will have to pick a different font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jarads solution of adding a line height of 0.8 and bottom padding of 8px resolved the issue in IE9 but did not resolve the issue in every other browser. Therefore I create an IE only CSS with Jarads solution and everything is OK now.

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers will have different default settings for things like padding, margins, and line-heights. Be sure that you have reset the default styles equally across them.

Comment: I'm thinking this should probably be a comment under the question. :)